# A graph problem

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am struggling to solve the following problem

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/1/193.html

However Im not able to get a fast solution.

And as seen by the times of others, there should be a solution of maximum n^2 complexity

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problemid=129&page=problem_stats

Can I get some help?

Comment: How far have you gotten?  What kind of code have you written?

Comment: This problem is NP-complete and I think all passed with optimized bruteforces or incorrect greedys.

Comment: @Sev 
I did a brute force on all combinations of vertices and in each step found a clique of size x.Then I deleted all vertices which were not a part of this. Then I did brute force for a clique of size x+1 with the remaining vertices.This continued until there was no clique of size x. Obviously this is too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only solve this in exponential complexity, but that's not as bad as it sounds, because in practice you'll be able to avoid a lot of bad decisions and thus reduce the running time of the algorithm significantly.

In short, you have to run a DF search from a node and try to color as many nodes black as you can. If you're at a node that has neighboring black nodes, that node can only be white. Keep doing this for every possibility of coloring a specific node.

If you can't figure it out, then check these two code snippets I found by googling for the problem name: [one](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://www.cppblog.com/rakerichard/archive/2010/01/09/105295.html&ei=Bf0RTNSpC86jOJvEyOQH&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBkQ7gEwADgK&prev=/search%3Fq%3Duva%2Bgraph%2Bcoloring%26start%3D10%26hl%3Den%26safe%3Doff%26sa%3DN%26rlz%3D1G1GGLQ_ENZZ360) and [two](http://www.wretch.cc/blog/celiaailec/21035297). The authors say they get AC, but I haven't tested them. They look correct however.

Answer (score 0):

It is solving the problem called maximum clique, also called maximum independent set or maximum stable set. It is NP-Complete. Fastest code I know for small graphs is Cliquer: http://users.tkk.fi/pat/cliquer.html

If you are writing your own for educational purposes it is probably most efficient to do a depth first search coloring nodes black one at a time and retreating up the DFS if two black nodes are touching.

The easiest to code solution is implementing a binary counter and trying all 2^n possibilities.

Comment: All 2^n possibilies? - 2^100 will hurt pretty hard:)

Comment: what will be the complexity of the dfs??

Comment: @copperhead - it will also be `O(2^n)` in theory, but it will work much faster in practice because you'll be able to eliminate a lot of invalid solutions very fast. If you do it like that you'll surely get AC.

Comment: @|V|ad - Can u briefly describe what kind of algo do u have in mind??

Comment: @Chad: To nitpick. Maximum clique and Maximum independent set are different problems. For instance finding maximum independent set in a planar graph is NP-Complete, which is not the case for maximum clique for planar graphs. For general graphs, yes, finding max ind set in G is same as finding the max clique in the complement of G, but they are different problems.

Comment: @Moron: I was mentioning alternate keywords to search on. Of course you would have to take the complement of the graph to use one algorithm as an oracle for the other.

@copperhead, @Petar Yes. 2^n is nasty :p   Cliquer and similar algorithms do an intelligent DFS that prunes off partial solutions when a more optimal one is already found. The keyword is "branch and bound".

Answer (score 0):

[Bron–Kerbosch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm)

I have solved a similar problem on FaceBook puzzles, I used the B-K algo for that.

Comment: What is the meaning of the '\' in pseudocode i.e. ( P \ N(u) )

Comment: It means the set P without N(u)

Comment: I found a sample code (ruby): http://kanwei.com/code/2009/03/26/facebook-peaktraffic.html

Comment: well, I don't understand Ruby, so do u mind explaining the algo used??